# Slick Grid - change color for selected row

Tags: slickgrid

In slick grid, I can change the color of a specific row with:

```
$('.slick-row[row=2]').addClass('colorTest');
```

I wish to replace 2 with a variable in the command above.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't quite see what the problem is. Why can't you just do...

```
var i;
i = 2;

$('.slick-row[row=' + i + ']').addClass('colorTest');
```

Comment: that solved the problem - I did not think of using the "+" in front of the variable name

Answer (score 1):

This will not work.  SlickGrid creates and removes DOM elements dynamically as you scroll, so if you do this, then scroll down a page and then scroll back up, your style will disappear.

SlickGrid defines an API for the data provider to specify CSS classes that should be applied to different rows and/or cells - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid.

Comment: True, but I find there are still places where I need to speak to the DOM directly. I had to use the same technique as OP to add mouseover highlighting to rows. I couldn't see any properties exposing mouseover css classes (or maybe I missed them). And for mouseover effects the issue of scrolling out of the viewport is not relevant.